# easyautocomplete scroll issue

Tags: css, autocomplete, scrollbar, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have used jquery easyautocomplete (from http://easyautocomplete.com/) to make a suggestion/autocomplete box but this doesn't have scrollbar when the list is too long. As a result I have to scroll the whole page to get to the bottom of the list.

If anyone knows a solution please share.

Thanks

Comment: You need to phrase it as a question and then add an answer, otherwise this *question* will get closed. It is [allowed to answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and you have enough reputation (>15) to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Dear fellow programmers,

Whoever is using "easyautocomplete" from http://easyautocomplete.com/ and having an issue of not having a scrollbar for the list, the following is a quick workaround. There are many other issues but right now i do not have enough time to work on them. In future if I can get a chance to solve them and in the mean time they aren't fixed by the owner I will give it a go and share with you lot.

Till then open your easy-autocomplete.css file and alter the following block of code:

```
.easy-autocomplete-container ul {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffffff;
  border-top: 1px dotted #ccc;
  display: none;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
  max-height:150px; /* Set your expected height */
  overflow-y:scroll; /* Enable vertical scrollbar */
}
```

Also if anyone is worrying about only 6 (six) returns in the list following is the solution for that:

Open the jquery.easy-autocomplete.min.js or jquery.easy-autocomplete.js and alter the value for **maxNumberOfElements** which in my case was **6** by default.

The last two lines of the code actually does the trick. Also I havent checked the outcome if you use additional theme with it, therefore I'm sorry if you face any problem with that.

If anyone else find a better solution please feel free to share with others.

Thanks & Happy Programming

Update:
The following link gives a better solution:
http://gnnc.com.br/samples/easy-autocomplete/easy-autocomplete.php

Answer (score 1):

set `maxNumberOfElements:500` on `jquery.easy-autocomplete.min.js` file for large lists

## for scrolling:

add these two properties on `easy-autocomplete.min.css` file

```
.easy-autocomplete-container {
    max-height: 150px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your Easy Autocomplete container a fixed height and add overflow:scroll.

Here is an example of the CSS you could use:

```
.easy-autocomplete-container { max-height:100px; overflow:scroll; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but overflow:scroll will give you a horizontal scrollbar as well. So I did overflow-y:scroll. Also if you alter .easy-autocomplete-container class that will make the scrollbar longer than the ul container so you need to alter ".easy-autocomplete-container ul" class.